# How to terminate python.exe*32 process when I exit my application?

Tags: python, windows, memory, process

I have written a python (2.7) application using wxpython GUI under Windows 7. When I run the application, I see that a `python.exe*32` process starts in task manager. When I exit the application (close the GUI window with `Window.Close()` method of wxpython), `python.exe*32` process remains there. When I run the application again, a 2nd python.exe*32 process starts, and it goes on and on. Each `python.exe*32` process takes around 180 MB memory, and it slows down the computer.

I start my application this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow("MyApp")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

How do I make `python.exe*32` process terminated when I exit my application?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you start your python application?  (`sys.exit(1)` should terminate all child and parent processes)

Comment: Please see my question, I updated it.

Comment: I ment, how do you start the entire python code, like: "python whambam.py" or?

Comment: I use Eclipse with PyDev, and I click the "run" button on the toolbar.

Comment: There you have it. Try and see if `sys.exit(1)` terminates the parent process. If not try `os._exit(1)` (I just say this because i have no real knowledge of how Eclipse launches it's subprocess python.exe*32 :) And also if you have any threads in your application, be sure to terminate/stop them as well. And place the `sys.exit(1)` after `app.MainLoop()` and make sure the `app` is exiting properly by perhaps inserting a `print("moo")` between `app.MainLoop()` and `sys.exit(1)`

Comment: Thanks, I added `sys.exit(1)` after `self.Close()` and it worked.

Comment: glad it worked, wrote a "solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `sys.exit(1)` at the end of your code, this will give the parent process a return code which in tern should terminate the parent that is Python.

Note:
Do not place `sys.exit(1)` right after the GUI "close" function if you have threads running separately, this will cause data-loss and "screw up" open sockets if you have any of those.

This is the right way to do it:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(350,200))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Destroy() # or simply do sys.exit(1) here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow("MyApp")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: please tell me also how to kill the python.exe*32 when I click the "X" button on top-right of my application window, because when I click "X", application window closes, but python.exe*32 process remains in task manager

Comment: But you sad it worked? Worked == the process dies, have you tried both `sys.exit(1)` and `os._exit(1)` and none of them terminated the process?

Comment: It works when I use the "Exit" menu item in "File" menu of the application, because I added sys.exit() to "Exit"'s binded function. But no function is binded "X" button, thus it doesnt call sys.exit()

Comment: Think logically for a second, if the "Exit" menu item works because it will execute `sys.exit(1)`, but the close button don't, that's because the close button terminates the GUI without calling the close function which you have only registered to the "Exit" menu item.
**as i sad numerous of times** don't place `sys.exit(1)` on the Exit button, place it **AFTER** `app.MainLoop()` so that you call `sys.exit(1)` at any given time the GUI closes/exits/collapses.

Comment: Each button **including menu items** have a registered function bound to it.. for instance `closeBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)` "closeBtn" is bound to `self.onClose`, however the Minemize, Maxemize and Close buttons in the corner of your application is a windows-manager specific button bound to default functions within the graphical library. They do not call home-made functions out of the box. This is why you need to call `sys.exit(1)` OUTSIDE of your graphical library.. Otherwise you'll need to catch the `close` event calling `def _when_closed(self, event):`

Comment: But I did place `sys.exit(1)` after `app.MainLoop()`, it doesnt work. I also added a print statement after `app.MainLoop()` to check if it is executed when I clixk "X" but it is not executed. I think statements after `app.MainLoop()` are not executed when "X" is clicked

Comment: Check my edit, register the close event to a function and call it there.

Comment: I have to take it back, it works, thank you very much, best regards